# Botão para voltar para div inicial

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria que depois da ultima parte do teste, ele tivesse um botão encerrar para voltar para a pagina inicial, onde tem o botão iniciar teste, tentei com a opção `document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>')` mas não deu certo

```
var testCounter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = '';
    var testEnabled = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;
    var contaBotao = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
      sensorValor = $('#counter').text();
    }), 100;

    $(".meubotao").click(function(e){
      $('#contador').show();

      var len = $('.testes div').length;

      // //Se for a primeira vez ele é 0 então não entrará, mas na segunda vez 
      //  ele entra no if e pega a div anterior "testCounter-1"
      if (len > testCounter){
        if(contaBotao > 0){
            $('.testes div').eq(testCounter-1).hide();
            $('#contador').show();
        }
        contaBotao++;
        $('.testes div').eq(testCounter).show();
        testCounter++;
        if (len == testCounter){
          $('.meubotao').hide(); //ultima etapa ja chegou
        } else {
          $('.meubotao').html('Próxima Etapa');
          $('.meubotao').addClass('proxEtapa');
        }


      }
    });
      function showDivcontador(){
      document.getElementById("meubotao").style.display = 'block';
      }
});
```

html

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TESTE DO FREIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/botao.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/conteudo.css">

  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
    html{
      overflow-y:hidden;
      overflow-x:hidden;
    -->
      }
  </style>

  </head>

<body>

<div id="imagem1"></div>  

<div id="contador"></div>

<label id="counter">0</label>

<div id="teste"></div>

<a class="meubotao">INICIAR TESTE</a>

<div class=testes>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="primeiro">1. Pressione e solte o pedal de freio do estacionamento várias vezes para checar se a pressão diminuiu.</div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="segundo">2. Drene a pressão do tanque de ar pelo cricuito frontal apenas para checar se a pressão mostra no contador do circuito frontal. Note que o contador do freio de estacionamento irá cair na mesma proporção do circuito da frente. O contador do circuito traseiro não deve se mover. </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="terceiro">3. Drene a pressão do tanque de ar pelo circuito traseiro apenas para checar se a pressão mostra no contador do circuito traseiro. Não tem necessidade de drenar o tanque de ar por completo. O contador do circuito dianteiro não deve se mover.<p>Pontos de inspeção para o teste com o contador</p><p>Abasteça o sistema de pressão para<span class="vermelho"> >9,3 bar</span>.</p><p>Trabalhe com a pressão<span class="vermelho"> >9,3 bar</span> no contador C (Circuito de freio de serviço).</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="quarto">4. Teste para verificar se os tubos de circuito traseiro e dianteiro está conectados corretamente no válvula de freio do serviço.
  E teste da válvula de freio secundário.
  Se o tubo de freio pelo circuito frontal e traseiro estiverem misturados, tem um risco de falha de freio
  <p>Esvazie (drenando) o tanque de ar pelo circuito frontal, pressione o pedal do freio para checar se o contador B do cilindro do circuito traseiro indica pressão no freio e ( para caminhões com válvula de freio secundário FPC 3054A) cheque o contador F do cilindro do circuito frontal indica pressão entre<span class="vermelho"> 0,5-2,0 bar</span> com o pedal do freio acionado.</p>
  <p>Esvazie (drenando) o tanque de ar pelo circuito traseiro, pressione o pedal do freio e cheque se o contador F do circuito do cilindro frontal indica queda de pressão.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="quinto">5. Checando o freio de estacionamento. <p>A alavanca deve estar na posição de direção. Leia os valores no contador D (freio de estacionamento), a pressão deve ser entre <span class="vermelho">6 -8,5 bar.</span></p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="sexto">6. Teste de checagem da válvula do circuito do freio de estacionamento.<p>A pressão deve ser entre <span class="vermelho">6 bars</span> no contador D (circuito de freio de estacionamento)</p>
  <p>O freio de estacionamento deve estar na posição de condução e não pode ter pressão de ar no cilindro do freio de estacionamento.</p>
  <p>Esvazie o reservatório do freio de estacionamento, Aguarde 2 minutos e cheque se não tem pressão caindo no contador D (freio de estacionamento).</p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="setimo">7. Distribuição do freio (somente com freio de reboque) exeto para EBS.<p>Pressione o pedal do freio devagar, a pressão no contador A (freio do reboque) deve ser entre <span class="vermelho">0,1 -0,5 bar</span> maior que a pressão no contador E (circuito traseiro antes da válvula relê). Cheque antes da pressão no contador A alcance <span class="vermelho">6 bar.</span></p><p>Para caminhões com EBS um teste estatico não é possivel de se fazer.</p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="oitavo">8. Freio de estacionamento com checagem de posição:<p>Coloque a alavanca do câmbio para a posição do freio de emergência:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 6,5 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p><p>Coloque a alavanca de câmbio para posição de estacionamento:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 0 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="oitavo1">8. Freio de estacionamento com checagem de posição:<p>Coloque a alavanca do câmbio para a posição do freio de emergência:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 6,5 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p><p>Coloque a alavanca de câmbio para posição de estacionamento:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 6,5 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p><p>os valores nos contadores devem parar no mesmo level. Cheque a posição de controle movendo a alavanca de câmbio para 10 passos da posição de freio do estacionamento, contadores A e D <span class="vermelho">= 0 bar</span></p> 
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="nono">Valores do teste de freio com o contador no valor padrão.</div>
  </div>

<div class="footer">
&copy; 2017 PokaYoke Team | Elaborado por Felipe Deolindo
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode deixar o link `<a id="goback" href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>` no HTML com o CSS `#goback{ display: none; }` e adicionar a linha `$('#goback').show();` no código JavaScript quando o teste acabar.

```js
var testCounter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = '';
    var testEnabled = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;
    var contaBotao = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
      sensorValor = $('#counter').text();
    }), 100;

    $(".meubotao").click(function(e){
      $('#contador').show();
      
      var len = $('.testes div').length;

      // //Se for a primeira vez ele é 0 então não entrará, mas na segunda vez 
      //  ele entra no if e pega a div anterior "testCounter-1"
      if (len > testCounter){
        if(contaBotao > 0){
            $('.testes div').eq(testCounter-1).hide();
            $('#contador').show();
        }
        contaBotao++;
        $('.testes div').eq(testCounter).show();
        testCounter++;
        if (len == testCounter){
          $('.meubotao').hide(); //ultima etapa ja chegou
          $('#goback').show(); // <-- add aqui.
        } else {
          $('.meubotao').html('Próxima Etapa');
          $('.meubotao').addClass('proxEtapa');
        }
        

      }

    });
      

      function showDivcontador(){
      document.getElementById("meubotao").style.display = 'block';
      }
});
```

```css
#goback {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagem1"></div>  

<div id="contador"></div>

<label id="counter">0</label>

<div id="teste"></div>

<a class="meubotao">INICIAR TESTE</a>

<div class=testes>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="primeiro">1. Pressione e solte o pedal de freio do estacionamento várias vezes para checar se a pressão diminuiu.</div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="segundo">2. Drene a pressão do tanque de ar pelo cricuito frontal apenas para checar se a pressão mostra no contador do circuito frontal. Note que o contador do freio de estacionamento irá cair na mesma proporção do circuito da frente. O contador do circuito traseiro não deve se mover. </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="terceiro">3. Drene a pressão do tanque de ar pelo circuito traseiro apenas para checar se a pressão mostra no contador do circuito traseiro. Não tem necessidade de drenar o tanque de ar por completo. O contador do circuito dianteiro não deve se mover.<p>Pontos de inspeção para o teste com o contador</p><p>Abasteça o sistema de pressão para<span class="vermelho"> >9,3 bar</span>.</p><p>Trabalhe com a pressão<span class="vermelho"> >9,3 bar</span> no contador C (Circuito de freio de serviço).</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="quarto">4. Teste para verificar se os tubos de circuito traseiro e dianteiro está conectados corretamente no válvula de freio do serviço.
  E teste da válvula de freio secundário.
  Se o tubo de freio pelo circuito frontal e traseiro estiverem misturados, tem um risco de falha de freio
  <p>Esvazie (drenando) o tanque de ar pelo circuito frontal, pressione o pedal do freio para checar se o contador B do cilindro do circuito traseiro indica pressão no freio e ( para caminhões com válvula de freio secundário FPC 3054A) cheque o contador F do cilindro do circuito frontal indica pressão entre<span class="vermelho"> 0,5-2,0 bar</span> com o pedal do freio acionado.</p>
  <p>Esvazie (drenando) o tanque de ar pelo circuito traseiro, pressione o pedal do freio e cheque se o contador F do circuito do cilindro frontal indica queda de pressão.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="quinto">5. Checando o freio de estacionamento. <p>A alavanca deve estar na posição de direção. Leia os valores no contador D (freio de estacionamento), a pressão deve ser entre <span class="vermelho">6 -8,5 bar.</span></p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="sexto">6. Teste de checagem da válvula do circuito do freio de estacionamento.<p>A pressão deve ser entre <span class="vermelho">6 bars</span> no contador D (circuito de freio de estacionamento)</p>
  <p>O freio de estacionamento deve estar na posição de condução e não pode ter pressão de ar no cilindro do freio de estacionamento.</p>
  <p>Esvazie o reservatório do freio de estacionamento, Aguarde 2 minutos e cheque se não tem pressão caindo no contador D (freio de estacionamento).</p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="setimo">7. Distribuição do freio (somente com freio de reboque) exeto para EBS.<p>Pressione o pedal do freio devagar, a pressão no contador A (freio do reboque) deve ser entre <span class="vermelho">0,1 -0,5 bar</span> maior que a pressão no contador E (circuito traseiro antes da válvula relê). Cheque antes da pressão no contador A alcance <span class="vermelho">6 bar.</span></p><p>Para caminhões com EBS um teste estatico não é possivel de se fazer.</p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="oitavo">8. Freio de estacionamento com checagem de posição:<p>Coloque a alavanca do câmbio para a posição do freio de emergência:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 6,5 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p><p>Coloque a alavanca de câmbio para posição de estacionamento:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 0 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="oitavo1">8. Freio de estacionamento com checagem de posição:<p>Coloque a alavanca do câmbio para a posição do freio de emergência:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 6,5 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p><p>Coloque a alavanca de câmbio para posição de estacionamento:</p><p>Contador A (serviço de reboque)<span class="vermelho"> ≥ 6,5 bar</span></p><p>Contador D (p-cilindro de freio)<span class="vermelho"> = 0 bar</span></p><p>os valores nos contadores devem parar no mesmo level. Cheque a posição de controle movendo a alavanca de câmbio para 10 passos da posição de freio do estacionamento, contadores A e D <span class="vermelho">= 0 bar</span></p> 
  </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="nono">Valores do teste de freio com o contador no valor padrão.</div>
  </div>

<div class="footer">
&copy; 2017 PokaYoke Team | Elaborado por Felipe Deolindo
</div>

<a id="goback" href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: então, o problema é que o valor do counter vem de um CLP que conta em bar, ele não é um valor fixo, e a ultima pagina não tem teste só informativo, no caso não tem com o que comparar

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Quando `len == testCounter` é o fim do teste não é? Então pode fazer...

Comment: consegui amigo, coloquei <a id="goback" href="index.html">Go Back</a>  e deu certo, obrigado

Comment: Coloca aí o endereço da página que tem que voltar no href do link... Coloquei esse código porque foi o que você colocou na pergunta `<a href="#EndereçoDaPaginaParaVoltar">Go Back</a>`

Comment: Vota a resposta como positiva então. Setinha pra cima!

Comment: já está votado ;D